# Include pymssql in py2app

Tags: python, macos, py2app, pymssql

I'm trying to package an app and include `pymssql` with it.

Here's my setup.py:

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['AppName.py']
DATA_FILES = ['pic1.jpg', 'pic2.jpeg']
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True,
           'packages': ['tkinter', '_mssql', 'pymssql']
           }

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

When I only include `_mssql` it gives this error:

```
error: cannot copy tree '/path_to_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/_mssql.so': not a directory
```

When I try with `pymssql` (or both) it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 20, in <module>
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/path_to_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 659, in run
    self._run()
  File "/path_to_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 865, in _run
    self.run_normal()
  File "/path_to_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 939, in run_normal
    mf = self.get_modulefinder()
  File "/path_to_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 814, in get_modulefinder
    debug=debug,
  File "/path_to_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/modulegraph/find_modules.py", line 341, in find_modules
    find_needed_modules(mf, scripts, includes, packages)
  File "/path_to_venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/modulegraph/find_modules.py", line 266, in find_needed_modules
    path = m.packagepath[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Another note:

I can package the app fine without including either `pymssql` or `_mssql` in the setup file and when I try and run the app, here's the error I get in the OS Console:

```
1/12/16 10:00:48.618 AM AppName[72301]: Traceback (most recent call last):
1/12/16 10:00:48.618 AM AppName[72301]:   File "/path_to_app/dist/AppName.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 351, in <module>
1/12/16 10:00:48.618 AM AppName[72301]:     _run()
1/12/16 10:00:48.619 AM AppName[72301]:   File "/path_to_app/dist/AppName.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 336, in _run
1/12/16 10:00:48.619 AM AppName[72301]:     exec(compile(source, path, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
1/12/16 10:00:48.619 AM AppName[72301]:   File "/path_to_app/dist/AppName.app/Contents/Resources/AppName.py", line 9, in <module>
1/12/16 10:00:48.619 AM AppName[72301]:     import pymssql
1/12/16 10:00:48.619 AM AppName[72301]:   File "_mssql.pxd", line 10, in init pymssql (pymssql.c:10984)
1/12/16 10:00:48.619 AM AppName[72301]: ImportError: No module named '_mssql'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround. Probably not the best way, but it works now.

I added `import _mssql` into my main app script (already had `import pymssql`).

I then took my `_mssql.pyx` file and put a copy in my app dir.

I added `_mssql.pyx` under the `DATA_FILES` in the `setup.py` file.

You will need to include `decimal` and `uuid` into your `setup.py` file if not already included somewhere else.

Leave `pymssql` and `_mssql` out of the `packages` list in the `setup.py` file as `py2app` will find them and include them automatically.

You may need to include other libraries that the `_mssql.pyx` file will try and import. Just keep adding them until it works.